# How do you pass class-defined variables into a method of the class using PHP?

Tags: php, function, class, variables, methods

I'd like to pass the value of the variables I've defined in a class to its method. I know that I can set a default value within the brackets of my method using an `=` sign, but it seems redundant since I've already defined the variables. Is this possible?

```
class Car {

    var $num_wheels = 4;
    var $model = "BMW";

    function MoveWheels($num_wheels, $model) {
        echo "The $num_wheels wheels on the $model are spinning.";
    }
}

$bmw = new Car();
$bmw -> MoveWheels();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question! You can pass class-defined variables into a method using `$this->`. Doing so eliminates placing variables within your method's brackets entirely.

```
class Car {

    var $num_wheels = 4;
    var $model = "BMW";

    function MoveWheels() {
        echo "The $this->num_wheels wheels on the $this->model are spinning.";
    }
}

$bmw = new Car();
$bmw -> MoveWheels();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial question was `I'd like to pass the value of the variables I've defined in a class to its method`. This doesn't involve necessary changing the method definition.

```
$bmw=new Car();
$bmw->MoveWheels($bmw->num_wheels,$bmw->model);
//maybe if needed, change param visibility 
//public $num_wheels
```